# How come the quality of HEVC with alpha from my ffmpeg with videotoolbox is not ok

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, alpha, hevc

I'm encoding ProRes 4444 with alpha channel video's to transparent video for web in both VP9 (webm) and HEVC (mp4). I'm using a great [free tool by Rotato](https://rotato.app/tools/converter) to encode to both formats at once.

However, because I would like to have more control over e.g. the dimensions and the bitrate, I'm looking into ffmpeg. I can encode to both formats with the following params.

```
# vp9
ffmpeg -i in.mov -vf scale=-1:720 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -auto-alt-ref 0 -pix_fmt yuva420p -acodec libvorbis -cpu-used 3 -deadline good -crf 40 out.webm 

# hevc
ffmpeg -i in.mov -vf scale=-1:720 -c:v hevc_videotoolbox -allow_sw 1 -alpha_quality 0.9 -tag:v hvc1 -q:v 65 out.mp4
```

The problem: the videotoolbox encoder generates a weird white garbage around the black pencil animations and fade-in's from transparent to black pencil become fade-in's from white pencil to black pencil!?

Here are screenshots of the two compared (top one is my ffmpeg output):

[image: hevc]

[image: rotato]

Anyone have good settings for ffmpeg I cano use to encode good quality HEVC with alpha?
Hardware: MacBook Air M1 and Win11 + GTX 1060 (I should be able to use NVEnc, but don't know how)

Comment: Have you tried to encode it with x265? I wonder if you are seeing artifacts from HW encoder

Comment: Yes, but x265 has no option to encode alpha, so that's not an option

Comment: Can you provide your input file?

Comment: Apart from being a file of 8Gb in size, I may not publish that file, because it's property of my client..

Comment: Here's a free online example vid to test with: https://www.vecteezy.com/video/20153377-hand-draw-symbol-icon-2d-animation-alpha-channel. See below for an answer from @Kajuna

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For me, the solution was to use the premultiply filter

> -vf premultiply=inplace=1

Comment: That totally solved the white artifacts @Kajuna ! Thanks so much!

Comment: In addition to this, I lowered the quality to compensate for bigger filesize when using premultiply. My new full command is now `ffmpeg -i in.mov -vf scale=-1:720 -c:v hevc_videotoolbox -allow_sw 1 -alpha_quality 0.9 -tag:v hvc1 -q:v 35 -vf premultiply=inplace=1 out.mp4`

Comment: Yes of course, I should have done so already. Sorry you had to ask ;-)

Comment: I see now that I have double filter options, you should specify them in one option like this: `ffmpeg -i in.mov -vf "scale=-1:720, premultiply=inplace=1" -c:v hevc_videotoolbox -allow_sw 1 -alpha_quality 0.9 -tag:v hvc1 -q:v 35 out.mp4`. 

The space behind the commas in the video options really do matter :-/

Answer (score 0):

Before the options I would check the system preferences to retain the alpha channel transparency more from [Larry here](https://larryjordan.com/articles/include-transparency-alpha-channels-in-hevc-video/), they are build natively - see the two options larry has on his site.

> Check to ensure in System Preferences > Keyboard.
> The Services category on the left,
> then select enable Encode Selected Video Files on the right.
> From any video application, export a project that contains transparency directly using the ProRes 4444 codec.
> Then, in the Finder, right-click the resulting .mov and select Services -> Encode Selected Video Files.
> Wait a few seconds for the next menu to appear.

[image]

---

**Seems like you are looking for the encoder and bitrate options, you can list them out fully as below**

> Option 1: **`H.264` encoder**

```
// Help you understand the ***H.264 encoder's options.
ffmpeg -hide_banner -h encoder=h264_nvenc | xclip -sel clip

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

> Option 1: **`HEVC/H.265` encoder**

```
// Help you understand the **H.265 encoder's options.
ffmpeg -hide_banner -h encoder=h264_nvenc | xclip -sel clip
```

> Now for `bitrates`, setup values using `-b:v`, `-maxrate:v` and `-bufsize:v` options

And since you have Mac Hardware - if you type this it will tell your configuration.

```
 ~ ffmpeg -h encoder=hevc_videotoolbox
```

Once you have this you can choose to tweak it in the configuration, rebuild and  yourself.. with different options look here for build on [VM + Apple M1](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/2187) and here for the [encoding Support for Apple Silicon M1 encoders](https://github.com/cdgriffith/FastFlix/issues/196)

Comment: I'm confused. I'm not sure why I should use the 'encode video' from services. I've done that and I have no control over the bitrate, so the video gets very large in filesize. But more important, I cannot automate it. 

I'm also not sure what to do / expect from the above ffmpeg commands. The first two don't work (command xclip not found) and the third one shows me options I was already using.  It's just that the black painted lines in the animation have white rubbish around them at any bitrate / quality

Comment: Hey Jos, did you find a solution or make any progress on this? Thx!

Comment: Jos or @Mike , did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Yes, finaly I can encode with ffmpeg, thanks to @Kajuna 's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76569133/757201